# API Gateway Cutom Authorizer ID in AWS Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

For other resources I'm able to get ID in breadcrumb but not for Custom Authorizer.

Where I can find Custom authorizer Id in AWS console?

Found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/836075/aws-api-gateway-custom-authorizer-whats-the-id-of-my-custom-authorizer) reference, but I guess AWS UI changed.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution (Couldn't find in AWS console):

Try using below AWS CLI command:

```
aws apigateway get-authorizers --rest-api-id <your-api-id>
```

Above command will give you following output

[image]

HIH